# how can generate apk file from installed android application?

Tags: android

Hi android developers I got an issue from android development. Actually one android app I installed in my mobile successfully it is installed. But I want my apk file from  installed app. How can I get suggest me thanks!!

Comment: there are lots of app available on play store for apk share.download one of them and share your apk to other device.You can not manually share apk.

Comment: see link https://play.google.com/store/search?q=apk%20share&hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All installed APKs are located in **/data/app/**, but you can see this if you have **rooted device**

If you don't wants to root your device then there are many application available in market such as MyAppSharer

MyAppSharer is available on google play store.

[Download MyAppSharer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yschi.MyAppSharer&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS55c2NoaS5NeUFwcFNoYXJlciJd)

The APKs will goes in /sdcard/MyAppSharer

Comment: ok I will check and I will let u inform u #AndroidWeblineindia thanks

Comment: Its too late to answer this question, but GoBackUp app is also helpful for this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution.
First there are two types of application in android devices

1. Default application (i.e. installed by manufacture)
2. From third party app(i.e from play store etc)

If you want apk of the third party application connect your android device  in your computer and launch android studio.
Open **Device File Explore --> data -->app**. Right click on the apk you want and save it on your local device(i.e computer);
[image]

For the default app which installed by manufacture repeat the previous procedure but in this step go to **Device File Explore --> system -->app.** Right click on apk you want and save it.

[image: l]